# KVM VM which MAC address to give hosting company (Fasthosts)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, kvm-virtualization, hypervisor

To allow traffic to be routed through there network for my KVM VM my hosting company want to know the MAC address.  The way I have it set up is my VM used a different IP from the host.  I have bridges and the VM (which uses the second IP I got from hosting company), they all seem to have mac addresses.  So what will the MAC address the hosting company see (coming out of my VM via the host.  The second IP is only set up on the VM, noware else.

They also want to know the IP, the secondary IP I have set up on the VM?

The host is CentOS and the guest is Ubuntu 16.04.

Fasthosts support is a bit rubish so cant get help from them.

My VM has a MAC address and the has has the following:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig -a
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet xxx.171.204.107 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 213.171.204.107
inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe43:92df prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:df txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 4418472 bytes 3176695519 (2.9 GiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1685001 bytes 3467150762 (3.2 GiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

br-369501bb177f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 172.18.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.18.255.255
inet6 fe80::42:22ff:fe7c:d452 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 02:42:22:7c:d4:52 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
RX packets 4418472 bytes 3176695519 (2.9 GiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1685005 bytes 3467151466 (3.2 GiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

enp7s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet xxx.171.204.107 netmask 255.255.252.0 broadcast 213.171.207.255
inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe43:92df prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:df txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 76116319 bytes 47205826581 (43.9 GiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 10 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 217240694 bytes 282949224905 (263.5 GiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device memory 0xfa200000-fa27ffff

enp8s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:e0 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device memory 0xfa100000-fa17ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 1924639 bytes 230337577 (219.6 MiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1924639 bytes 230337577 (219.6 MiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255
ether 52:54:00:56:31:0e txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 52:54:00:56:31:0e txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe3e:e407 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether fe:54:00:3e:e4:07 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 5190 bytes 218916 (213.7 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 767907 bytes 194377408 (185.3 MiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 27442 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the MAC of the VM I needed to give them.  They were actually a little more helpful than normal.